# List of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to make a list of arrays in JAVASCRIPT but my program doesn't do what I expect.

I want to make a list of arrays like this:

```
var myListofArrays;

var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var secondArray = [6,5,4,3,2,1];
var thirdArray = [1,1,1];
```

I want to add those arrays in myListArray to finally get something like that:

```
myListofArrays[0] = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
myListofArrays[1] = [6,5,4,3,2,1];
myListofArrays[2] = [1,1,1];
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `myListOfArrays` is `undefined`. Initialize it with `= []`. Or just do it all in one nested literal `var myListOfArrays = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6], [6,5,4,3,2,1], [1,1,1] ];`

Comment: Also should see that it is undefined by looking at error thrown in browser console...big clue there

Answer (score 10):

Starting from:

```
var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var secondArray = [6,5,4,3,2,1];
var thirdArray = [1,1,1];
```

You only need create a new array object:

```
var myListOfArrays = [];
```

and then, insert all arrays that you want into the new array:

```
mylistOfArrays.push(firstArray);
mylistOfArrays.push(secondArray);
mylistOfArrays.push(thirdArray);
```

With push() method the array object is added at end of the new array. This method also returns the new length.

You can visit this reference to get a detailed list of array methods: [Array Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

Comment: there is a typo: mylistOfArrays.push should be myListOfArrays.push

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do this. Try:

```
var myListofArrays = [];

var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var secondArray = [6,5,4,3,2,1];
var thirdArray = [1,1,1];

myListofArrays.push(firstArray);
myListofArrays.push(secondArray);
myListofArrays.push(thirdArray);
```

Or a little fancier:

```
myListofArrays.push(firstArray, secondArray, thirdArray);
```

Or:

```
var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    secondArray = [6,5,4,3,2,1],
    thirdArray = [1,1,1],
    myListOfArrays = [firstArray, secondArray, thirdArray];
```

And there are still probably plenty other valid ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Beside [Andrew Clavin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38192414/19068) you can also try this:

```
var myListofArrays =[];

var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var secondArray = [6,5,4,3,2,1];
var thirdArray = [1,1,1];

myListofArrays[0]=firstArray;
myListofArrays[1]=secondArray;
myListofArrays[2]=thirdArray;

console.log(myListofArrays);
```

check it in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcygbLq6/1/)

Comment: @squint Yes you are right, before I want to post the complete answer Andrew Calvin posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you are almost there.

Try this:

```
var myListofArrays = [];
```

You need to declare your variable as an array before you start dumping things in it.

**EDIT**

If you want to shorten down your code, you could also try this:

```
var myListofArrays = [];

var firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var secondArray = [6,5,4,3,2,1];
var thirdArray = [1,1,1];

myListofArrays = [firstArray, secondArray, thirdArray];
```

This will push all of your declared arrays into your master array(myListofArrays) and because you declared it as an array at the top, the javascript will understand it is an array and push the rest of the arrays in accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one mentioned the [**concat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#Examples) method. Here is my contribution:

```js
var myListofArrays = [];

var firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var secondArray = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var thirdArray = [1, 1, 1];

function concatAllArrays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (!Array.isArray(myListofArrays[i])) {
      myListofArrays[i] = [];
    }
    myListofArrays[i] = myListofArrays[i].concat(arguments[i]);
  }
}

concatAllArrays(firstArray, secondArray, thirdArray);
console.log('My array => ', myListofArrays);
```